# AngularJS router redirecting to #!/ instead of login page

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I am using AngularJS ngRouter in Spring MVC application. When application launched, it should redirect to login page (http://localhost:8080/TimeLee/login) . But it's redirecting to url **http://localhost:8080/TimeLee/#!/** instead of login page

[image: Redirected Page]

**index.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="index">
<head>
<title>Hello User</title>
<script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"> </script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>

    <script>

    var App = angular.module('index',[ 'ngRoute' ]);

    App.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) 
    {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/login', {
        templateUrl : 'login/login',
        controller : 'loadLoginPage'
        })
        .when('/home', {
                templateUrl : 'login/home',
                controller : 'loadLoginPage'
                })
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'login/',
            controller : 'loadLoginPage'
        })

        .otherwise({
            redirectTo : '/',
        });
        });

    App.controller('loadLoginPage', ['$window','$location', function($window,$location) 
    {
        //$window.location.href='http://localhost:8080/TimeLee/login/';
    }]);

   </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-ng-controller="loadLoginPage">            
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Main Controller:**

```
package com.timelee.common.controllers;

import com.timelee.common.services.LoginService;
import com.timelee.users.model.User;

import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class MainController
{
    @Autowired
    private LoginService loginService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public  String getLogin()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside /login");
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public  String loadLoginPage()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside /");
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/loginAction",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<HashMap> loginAction(@RequestParam("user_name") String user_name,@RequestParam("user_password") String user_password, HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        HashMap map=loginService.validateLogin(user_name,user_password);
        return  ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED).body(map);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/home",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String redirectHome()
    {
        return "login";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/homepage",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loadHomePage()
    {
        return "home";

    }

}
```

Comment: Why did you comment   $window.location.href='http://localhost:8080/TimeLee/login/';

Answer (score 0):

First change your otherwise route to below shown & remove "/" route

```
.otherwise({
       redirectTo : '/login',
 });
```

This will redirect your page to login page but there'll still be # in your url (default hashbang mode). To remove that you've to use $location service's provider i.e. `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` inside config block of your angular module. This will re-write url to simple html5 mode.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

For adding templates for different routes follow official documentation structure.

Comment: It did not solve my issue. It's replacing application name with "/login". End url looks like this 'http://localhost:8080/login'

Comment: @John If you want the url to be exact then, just add route in when methods "path" as /TimeLee/login , /TimeLee/home so following my above answer redirectTo url will be /TimeLee/login (everything else should be same). And also template url needs to have template file path, if you're having that from backend then it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that when you're working with AngularJS as your front-end framework, you're no longer work with model & view like you normally do when working with JSP as your template engine.

You need to make your application load your index main page, the page where angularJS injects its views. And you'll to communicate using HTTP REST between your Spring Controllers and AngularJS.

Your actual routing and views switching will be taken place in your AngularJS front-end using `$location.path("/your/path")`

**What you're getting: `#!/`
Is prefectly normal in AngularJS, this is how AngularJS treats his routes and inject its proper requested view.**